# SQLException: no such table

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

now I got some trouble connecting to my database. I know the tables i am looking for exist because when I access them with the command line they can be queried.

Probably some minor oversight but I would love some help.

This is where I make my connection to my database
    package persistence;

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class DBRegistry {

    private static DBRegistry db = null;
    private static Connection connection = null;

    private DBRegistry() {};

    public static synchronized DBRegistry getUniqueInstance() {
        if (db == null) {
                db = new DBRegistry();
                return db;
        }
        else return db;
    }

    public synchronized Connection getDBConnection() {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/database/taskMan.db");
                return connection;
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            return null;
    }

    public synchronized void closeConnection() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I query it

```
public void create(UUID oid, Object obj) {
    Task t = (Task)obj;
    String statement = "INSERT INTO `complexTask` (`oid`,`description`,`status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement dbStatement = db.prepareStatement(statement);
        dbStatement.setString(1, oid.toString());
        dbStatement.setString(2, t.getDescription());
        dbStatement.setBoolean(3, t.getStatus());
        dbStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and finally a stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: no such table: complexTask
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:37)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:231)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:224)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:213)
    at persistence.framework.ComplexTaskRDBMapper.create(ComplexTaskRDBMapper.java:23)
    at persistence.PersistanceFacade.create(PersistanceFacade.java:49)
    at persistence.persistanceStates.NewState.commit(NewState.java:10)
    at persistence.PersistentObject.commit(PersistentObject.java:23)
    at domain.objects.Task.commitToDB(Task.java:89)
    at domain.TaskRepository.commitToDB(TaskRepository.java:60)
    at domain.TaskController.persistanceCommit(TaskController.java:97)
    at presentation.TaskControlsJPanel$3.actionPerformed(TaskControlsJPanel.java:127)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2012)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2335)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:404)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:253)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6175)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5940)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2105)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4536)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4362)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4461)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4125)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4055)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2149)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4362)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:604)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

And some JUnit code for good measure, the first test passes and the second fails with a similar error to the one above

```
package test.persistence;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import persistence.DBRegistry;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TestDBRegistry extends TestCase {

    public void testDBRegistryConnection() {
        Connection con =  DBRegistry.getUniqueInstance().getDBConnection();
        assertNotNull(con);
    }

    public void testTableQuery() throws SQLException {
        Connection con =  DBRegistry.getUniqueInstance().getDBConnection();
        PreparedStatement dbStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `singleTask`");
        assertEquals("should be 1 for successful query", 1, dbStatement.executeQuery());
    }
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the path to the database is not set correctly but then wondered if that would have made th first unit test fail.

Comment: try `DBNAME.singleTask` as a shot it should work .

Comment: try connecting the same DB using some other front end to check the tables

Comment: @org.life.java I tried to use the command line and it worked out!
ben@ben-laptop:~/workspace/taskManager_v4/src/database$ sqlite taskManDb.db
SQLite version 2.8.17
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> .tables
complexTask    repeatingTask  singleTask     subTask

Comment: I'd same kinda experience with sqlite in iPHone app dev with CoCoa, at that time the issue was the command line was referring to some other DB and my app was referring to some other .sqlite file. make sure this thing

Comment: @org.life.java I have just double checked and can't find a discrepancy there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I notice that in both your unit test and your other code you are using back-ticks around the table name. In the latest version of sqlite, this is fine but in older versions it wasn't handled as well I believe. Can you try removing the ticks around the table name or maybe changing them to regular quotes rather than back-ticks?

If that doesn't solve it I would check to be absolutely sure that you are pointing to the correct db file. If you specify a filename that doesn't exist you won't get an error, it will simply create a new database there. I'm not sure what the "current directory" is under the context of your app or unit test but be sure it is pointing to where you think it is. To test this, you could change the db file name to `foo.db`, run the unit test, then search your machine for `foo.db` to see where it got created. That will tell you where your app is working off of.

Comment: I have played with the quotes and back-ticks and that didn't help. I will do some more playing around with paths and will keep you posted. Thanks for letting me know about no errors being thrown on a bogus DB name.

Comment: It was difficult deciding who should win the bounty on this one but I've decided to give it to Marplesoft for coming the closest. Using a fully qualified path for my database ended up doing the trick and this answer prompted me to launch an investigation into the details of the path, thus the points have been awarded. Thanks to all for your contributions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your JDBC connection string is quite right.  The connection string you use ends with `taskMan.db`, but your comment above implies that the name of the database file is `taskManDb.db` (note the extra `Db`).

Comment: In that case, your connection string should be `jdbc:sqlite:src/database/taskManDb.db`, not `jdbc:sqlite:src/database/taskMan.db`

Comment: Litytestdata thanks for that comment. I have made the changes but unfortunately that did not resolve the issue. I actually caught that mistake myself as well just after posting, glad you saw it too.

Answer (score 1):

It might not fix your problem with the SQL INSERT, but I don't care at all for your DBRegistry implementation.  I'd write it like this:

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class DBRegistry
{
    public static Connection getConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName(driver);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void close(Statement statement)
    {
        try
        {
            if (statement != null)
            {
                statement.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet resultSet)
    {
        try
        {
            if (resultSet != null)
            {
                resultSet.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately your solution did not solve the issue and so I will be issuing my bounty as a reward, however I would like to say thank you for commenting on the structure of the DBRegistry and I will certainly implement your solution there. Your version makes more sense than mine and I can't thank you enough for having taken the time to refactor my code.

Comment: Like I said at the start, I wasn't trying to solve your issue.  I don't have SQL Lite installed on my machine, so I can't try it.  But I will.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your table is in a package. so you might have do something like

```
select * from Tasks.ComplextTask
```

('Tasks' being the package)

Comment: @user521180 thanks for that response but unfortunately Tasks is not in a package. I appreciate your effort though.

Answer (score 0):

Now just try to find a file with the same name in c:\windows\system32 and you will find it. It tells to us that your path is not correct. Have a nice day;

Answer (score 0):

Please Commit your Connection after created table and after insertion.